# C#. Android and NFC

Tags: c#, android, nfc

I have a C# app running on my windows machine. The app can detect a specific phone (over bluetooth) and according to the phone's presence or not, it popups a message to the user. The C# app checks for the phone's presence periodically. So far so good.

I want to add a third "player" in the game i.e. an NFC smart card.

Now, I want the Android phone to act as an intermediate; it will receive the periodically sent request from the C# (windows machine) application, will check if a certain smart card is close (over NFC) and get back the answer to the C# application. So, now the C# app checks for both the phone's and (indirectly) the card's presence.

I want the application on the Android to constantly listen to the bluetooth interface and if the request from the C# (windows) application arrives, to check if the card is close. The answer ("yes" the card is here - "no" the card is not here) should be sent back to the C# application. I currently don't care about security or anything else. Only the existence of the card.

Do you think that this can be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, NFC in Android does not work that way. Its not as if the phone is "checking" if there are some cards near. Its event driven, not polling. When a card is put close enough to the phone, an aproriate intent is fired. your app can handle it.

As for your particular problem, the solution would seem to be setting up a flag each time a card is detected and feeding it to C# app via bluetooth. Remember tho, NFC isnt putting a card into a contact reader. The card may have been near the phone a second ago, but it might as well already be gone. Also, eep in mind, that NFC range is small - you have to almost touch the phone with the card.

On handling NFC intents check out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html

Answer (score 0):

I did not work with NFC-Tech or Android this far, but it should be possible.
Having the C#-Code constantly listening to the Android device is ok, like you said, you will need your android device to route the NFC-Listener.

When the Android device detects an NFC-Card, it should be easily given to the C# Code via some custom method.